# Connecting frontend and backend codes in PYTHON only

Tags: python, frontend, backend

So, I am completely new to app designing. I have created the frontend and the backend code for my project, but I have no idea on how to merge them both. My project is on emotion detection on a tkinter canvas. The frontend code will create the canvas, and the backend code will detect the emotion. Also the epochs are taking a very long time to download, is there any way to fasten is a bit, ofcourse I lessened the number, but lessening it too much makes the model underfitted.

I am attaching my both the frontend and backend codes below. Kindly help me if you can.

Frontend:

```
#Importing Libraries
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

#Tkinter canvas
root= tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 1200, height = 900, bg='blue')
canvas.pack()
root.title("Emotion Detector")
rootfont=('times',18,'bold')
l1 = tk.Label(root,text='Welcome to the Emotion Detector',width=30,font=rootfont)
canvas.create_window(600, 30, window=l1)
#l1.grid(row=1,column=1)
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Upload File', 
width=20,command = lambda:upload_file())
#b1.grid(row=2,column=1)
canvas.create_window(600, 80,window=b1)
def upload_file():
    global img
    f_types = [('Jpg Files', '*.jpg')]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
    b2 = tk.Button(root,image=img)
    #b2.grid(row=3,column=1)
    canvas.create_window(600, 400, window=b2)
root.mainloop()
```

And here I am attaching my backend code:

```
import sys, os  
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
  
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten  
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization,AveragePooling2D  
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy  
#from keras.optimizers import adam  
from keras.regularizers import l2  
from keras.utils import np_utils   
  
df=pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv')  
  
print(df.info())  
print(df["Usage"].value_counts())  
print(df.head())
X_train,train_y,X_test,test_y=[],[],[],[]  
  
for index, row in df.iterrows():  
    val=row['pixels'].split(" ")  
    try:  
        if 'Training' in row['Usage']:  
           X_train.append(np.array(val,'float32'))   
           train_y.append(row['emotion'])  
        elif 'PublicTest' in row['Usage']:  
           X_test.append(np.array(val,'float32'))  
           test_y.append(row['emotion'])  
    except:  
        print(f"error occured at index :{index} and row:{row}")  
  
  
num_features = 64  
num_labels = 7  
batch_size = 64  
epochs = 30  
width, height = 48, 48  
  
  
X_train = np.array(X_train,'float32')  
train_y = np.array(train_y,'float32')  
X_test = np.array(X_test,'float32')  
test_y = np.array(test_y,'float32')  
  
train_y=np_utils.to_categorical(train_y, num_classes=num_labels)  
test_y=np_utils.to_categorical(test_y, num_classes=num_labels)
#cannot produce  
#normalizing data between oand 1  
X_train -= np.mean(X_train, axis=0)  
X_train /= np.std(X_train, axis=0)  
  
X_test -= np.mean(X_test, axis=0)  
X_test /= np.std(X_test, axis=0)  
  
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)  
  
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 48, 48, 1) 
# print(f"shape:{X_train.shape}")  
##designing the cnn  
#1st convolution layer  
model = Sequential()  
  
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])))  
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size= (3, 3), activation='relu'))  
# model.add(BatchNormalization())  
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))  
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
  
#2nd convolution layer  
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))  
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))  
# model.add(BatchNormalization())  
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))  
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
  
#3rd convolution layer  
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))  
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))  
# model.add(BatchNormalization())  
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))  
  
model.add(Flatten())  
  
#fully connected neural networks  
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  
  
model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
# model.summary()  
  
#Compliling the model  
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy,  
              optimizer='adam',  
              metrics=['accuracy'])  
  
#Training the model  
model.fit(X_train, train_y,  
          batch_size=batch_size,  
          epochs=1,  
          verbose=1,  
          validation_data=(X_test, test_y),  
          shuffle=True)  
  
  
#Saving the  model to  use it later on  
fer_json = model.to_json()  
with open("fer.json", "w") as json_file:  
    json_file.write(fer_json)  
model.save_weights("fer.h5")  

import os  
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
from keras.models import model_from_json  
from keras.preprocessing import image  
  
#load model  
model = model_from_json(open("fer.json", "r").read())  
#load weights  
model.load_weights('fer.h5')



def emotion_analysis(emotions):
    objects = ['angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise', 'neutral']
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    plt.bar(y_pos, emotions, align='center', alpha=0.9)
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', pad=10,width=4,length=10)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    plt.ylabel('percentage')
    plt.title('emotion')

from skimage import io
from keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
objects = ('angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise', 'neutral')
img = image.load_img('happyboy.jpg', grayscale=True, target_size=(48, 48))
show_img=image.load_img('happyboy.jpg', grayscale=False, target_size=(200, 200))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

x /= 255

custom = model.predict(x)
#print(custom[0])
emotion_analysis(custom[0])

x = np.array(x, 'float32')
x = x.reshape([48, 48]);

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(show_img)
plt.show()

m=0.000000000000000000001
a=custom[0]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]>m:
        m=a[i]
        ind=i
        
print('Expression Prediction:',objects[ind])
```

Ofcourse, separately, they both work perfectly, there are no errors, but how should I merge them both?
Any help or advice would be appreciated.
Also, I have searched about it. But, I am not able to understand what is it trying to say, or how should I merge it.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I would put the frontend and the backend in classes. For instance `class App` for the frontend and `class Model` for the backend.
I recommand checking the [python documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) if you are unfamiliar with the syntax.
I would then import those classes in the main python file.
The frontend class would start the main loop and call a method that creates a thread to handle data, which would make the frontend responsive.
I recommand checking the following posts [How can I use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python) and [tkinter-thread](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-thread/).